# Add Multiple Fields to SignUpViewController on Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

The tutorial talks about adding in username, password, email, and additional for fields, and says you can alter the placeholder text, but there is nothing about adding more fields.

For example, in my Core _Users data, I added two columns, firstName and lastName.  I would like to add in two fields for these.  I also need to know how you can make sure that those fields get passed on to the data appropriately.  Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend building your own sign in/up view controller's. It'll be much easier that way.

Update:
After checking out the Parse docs, I found this:

```
signUpController.fields = (PFSignUpFieldsUsernameAndPassword
                               | PFSignUpFieldsSignUpButton
                               | PFSignUpFieldsEmail
                               | PFSignUpFieldsAdditional
                               | PFSignUpFieldsDismissButton);
```

With the focus on the `PFSignUpFieldsAdditional` property. It appears as if adding that to the bit mask will add the additional field to the view controller, just as the documentation says.

As far as retrieving data from that field, it looks as if the `PFSignUpViewController` has a property `signUpView`, which has a property `additionalField`.

When the sign up is successful, you should pull the value out of this field and assign it to the user, like in this example:

```
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user {
    NSString *additionalInformation = signUpController.signUpView.additionalField.text;

    user["additionalField"] = additionalInformation;
    [user saveInBackground];
}
```

If you need more fields than the ONE additional field Parse provides, you should create your own sign up controller.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question.  There is no documentation for doing that, only subclassing it to change things like placeholder text or images.  What I am asking is how to get it to communicate to add a new textField and send that textField to a specific column on the _Users data.

Comment: So in order to just add one more textField to the SignUp form, I would have to build my own sign-up form from scratch?  I can't just subclass it somehow and add a text field?

Comment: From what I can tell, yes. The `PFSignUpViewController` uses a `PFSignUpView` to present the fields, which has a finite number of options. You could attempt to subclass it, and try to override it's standard behavior, but that won't be the cleanest. I recommend creating your own because it'll be as flexible as you make it, and you won't have to battle with private, third-party code.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I went ahead and changed placeholder on additional field to First & Last Names and had it check to make sure the field contains a space before allowing you to sign up.  This way I can make sure additional in _User has the first and last name.  Helps out quite a bit from trying to make my own class for it.

Comment: This seems very limited (i.e.: just one extra field) .. surely the docs are clearly lacking in substance on this? I cannot imagine them coding a scenario like this for ONLY one additional field.